# Nested relations using `with` in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Can someone tell me, I have several model:
One **Item** has many → **Properties**, On Property has many → **Characteristics**
I can do like this:

```
return Item::find()->where(['code' => $code])->with('properties')->asArray()->one();
```

result:

```
{
  title: "Ванна чугунная Ностальжи 150 с ножками",
  new: "0",
  hit: "0",
  recommend: "0",
  properties: [
  {
    //lallala
  },
  {
    //lallala
  },
  ]
}
```

But i want nested rows (Characteristics) **in every property** how can i do that much elegant way?

Comment: Can you explain more?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [Yii guide on working with databases](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#relational-data):

> You can eagerly load deeply nested relations, such as `a.b.c.d`. All parent relations will be eagerly loaded. That is, when you call `with()` using `a.b.c.d`, you will eagerly load `a`, `a.b`, `a.b.c` and `a.b.c.d`.

So use `properties.characteristics`:

```
return Item::find()->where(['code' => $code])->with('properties.characteristics')->asArray()->one()
```