# how do i get two left join on different tables in yii2?

Tags: mysql, json, yii2

I have 3 tables (companies, services, params).
The relations between the tables is as follows:
a company has many services, 
a service has many params,
a service belongs to one company.
I'm trying to join the companies with the services and the services with the params and return it as a json.

my code is:

```
$query = Companies::find()
            ->joinWith('services')
            ->leftJoin('params', '`services`.`id` = `params`.`serviceid`')
            ->asArray()->all();
return $query;
```

However in the json i'm getting the relation between companies and services is working but the relation between services and params is not.

If it helps this is the json i'm getting:
[image: json file]

Can anyone please help me?
It looks like i'm missing something basic but can't figure out what it is.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It was a nested relation issue, instead of:

```
$query = Companies::find()
            ->joinWith('services')
            ->leftJoin('params', '`services`.`id` = `params`.`serviceid`')
            ->asArray()->all();
return $query;
```

the query should look like this:

```
$query = Companies::find()
            ->with('services.params')
            ->asArray()->all();
return $query;
```

Yii2 understands the nested relations automatically if it's correctly set in your models.
Thanks to this post [Nested relations using `with` in yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40304715/nested-relations-using-with-in-yii2)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Did you set up also relations between those models ? It is much more easier to use, especialy if you need to use that relation on more than just one place.

[Yii2 - Working with Relational Data](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#relational-data)

And then just use [ActiveQuery with() method](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequerytrait.html#with()-detail)

Comment: yeah. There is a relationship between companies and services, then services and companies. When I try to use with I have the error that company doesn't have a relation with params.