# Yii2 Nested relations in Rest results

Tags: yii2

I have a customer `table` and a `user` table, they have a M:M relationship set in `user_has_customer`.

The entire application is a Rest API, and i use `extraFields()` and `GET customers?expand=users` to get the connected users when looking at customers.

`user_has_customer` stores some additional information on when the user was assigned to the customer and a few other fields, and several fields can have the same combination of user and customer. To be able to update or delete a relation, I need the relation id (`user_has_customer.id`) to be visible when looking at customers.

This function will return the customer, and its related users:

```
public function getUsers() {
    return $this->hasMany(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id'])
        ->viaTable('user_has_customer', ['customer_id' => 'id'])
        ->select(['id', 'username']);
}
```

This function will return the user-customer relationship:

```
public function getUserRelations() {
    return $this->hasMany(UserHasCustomer::className(), ['customer_id' => 'id'])
        ->select(["id",
            "customer_id",
            "user_id",
            "created_by",
            "created_at"]);
}
```

But i would like to know how i can nest these relations, so the result looks like this:

```
{
    "id": 11148,
    ....
    "users": {
        "id": 1,
        "user_id": 1,
        "added": "2017-08-01 22:23:24"
        "user": {
            "id": 1,
            "username": "admin"
        }
    }
}
```

or even like this (like a MySQL join):

```
{
    "id": 11148,
    ....
    "users": {
        "id": 1,
        "user_id": 1,
        "added": "2017-08-01 22:23:24"
        "username": "admin"
    }
}
```

For some reason this will not work (the created SQL *is* correct, but the AR refuse to show the fields from `user` in the result):

```
public function getUserRelations() {
    return $this->hasMany(UserHasCustomer::className(), ['customer_id' => 'id'])
        ->joinWith('user', true)
-       ->select('*');
}
```

Comment: is very hard to simulate you code without db table but I will try to explain how to do that, fist you must to add in your UserHasCustomer a function to build relation on user (function getUser) and replace the ->joinWith to ->with(["userHasCusomer.user"])

Comment: see mayby this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40304715/nested-relations-using-with-in-yii2?rq=1

Comment: or look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40304715/nested-relations-using-with-in-yii2?rq=1

Comment: I've seen that question (you posted the same twice), but i believe the issue here is that when joins are made in relation definitions (as in `hasMany` or `hasOne`) something is changing. As I mentioned above, the correct SQL is ran, but AR is not populating any fields (probably since they are not defined in that model)